# Helping Git tools to follow renames

Tags: git

Git does not "track" file renames as such across history; Git tracks file *contents*, not file names. However there are are two simple, practical questions that are still unclear to me.

I know that viewing the history of a renamed file regards tweaking some heuristic parameter, and that different Git tools implement this (or not) to varying degrees. That is, just because it is *possible* to tell Git to detect renames based upon some e.g. 95% similarity threshold, it doesn't mean that all Git tools allow this, or that they implement it correctly if they do. (Trying to see the history of a renamed file in Eclipse causes agony.) However most tools seem to be able to follow changes within the same file if the file has not been renamed.

There are two easy things I as a developer *could* do that on the face of it would help tools follow renames. I just want to know if they would really help, or if it is pointless.

Let's assume I want to rename the file `foo.txt` to `bar.txt` and change a tiny portion of the contents (let's say 1%). (Yes, I understand that committing a `git mv` is the same as committing a `git rm` combined with a `git add` in the same commit.) Afterwards I want to be able to see the changes between `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`. Here are three ways I could do it:

- Commit the renames and changes at the same time.

  ```bash
  git mv foo.txt bar.txt
  # make changes to bar.txt
  git commit …
  ```
- Rename in one commit and modify in another commit.

  ```bash
  git mv foo.txt bar.txt
  git commit …
  # make changes to bar.txt
  git commit …
  ```

  In this case the rename involves 100% identical content. Afterwards the changes are made to the same file, `bar.txt`.

  Have I gained anything at all using this approach,and specifically am I gaining from a technical standpoint, if Git only follows content and not filenames? Does this approach help most tools follow renames in any way when viewing history?
- Rename in one commit and modify in another commit and then merge.

  If the second approach above helps in any way, then what if I do the same thing in a branch:

  ```bash
  git checkout -b foobar
  git mv foo.txt bar.txt
  git commit …
  # make changes to bar.txt
  git commit …
  git checkout main
  git merge foobar --no-ff
  ```

  In this case the rename involves 100% identical content. Afterwards the changes are made to the same file, `bar.txt`. However, the *merge* will be both renaming the file and modifying 1% of its content in the same merge commit.

  Despite the merge have I gained anything at all using this approach *in a branch*, or **does the branch merging negate any benefits of using this technique in a branch** (seeing that the merge commit will inevitably combine the rename and content modification into one commit)? Does using this approach in a branch help most tools follow renames in any way when viewing history?

If nothing else it would be helpful to know if these techniques would help using the Git CLI, VS Code, and Eclipse.

Comment: `Trying to see the history of a renamed file in Eclipse causes agony` Can you clarify what Eclipse does here that's undesirable?

Comment: @NickODell I don't want to get sidetracked too much with specific bugs of this or that implementation. The question here is more about whether certain actions will make it easier for tools across the board to follow history. Nevertheless for Eclipse agony see [Bug 434085](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434085) (marked as "resolved" but still part of the agony), [Bug 541120](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5411200), [Bug 564499](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564499), [Bug 374722](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374722), …

Comment: Worth pointing out that your third example as described would result in a fast-forward merge, which would be the same as your second example. You’re presumably more interested in how renames will be handled across non-fast-forward (e.g. recursive) merges.

Comment: @cmbuckley Thanks for pointing that out. (Usually I merge via GitHub/Bitbucket and maintain a separate merge commit to preserve history.) You're right, the idea is whether a merge commit would undo any benefits of order of renaming/modifying in the branch. I added a `--no-ff` flag to make this clear.

Comment: "Rename in one commit and modify in another commit." Yep, that's the way to go.

Comment: "Yep, that's the way to go." @matt Why? What benefits does that bring? And isn't the merge commit inherently a rename+modify in the same commit; wouldn't that defeat any benefits of separate commits in the branch?

Comment: Your question was: "Have I gained anything at all using this approach? Does this approach help most tools follow renames in any way when viewing history?" And I'm saying: Yes, it does.

Comment: Thank you for answering the literal question for the first scenario. If you'd like to answer the question for the second scenario, too, it would be much appreciated: "…, or does the branch merging negate any benefits of using this technique in a branch?" And I'll be sure to update the question to add "and what specifically would those benefits be from a technical standpoint?"

Comment: The merging business seems to me to come out of left field; I don't see what it has to do with anything. Git logging on the history of a file, as you yourself seem to know, works on the fly; it is an emergent property of the commit parent chain. If a file in commit A and a file in commit A-parent have the same name, they "are" the same file. If a file in commit A does not appear by that name in commit A-parent but a file with identical contents does, they "are" the same file with a rename. So if you are careful to rename-and-commit and then edit-and-commit, you enable reliable following.

Comment: "The merging business seems to me to come out of left field …" It's because the merge creates a new commit. This new commit will inevitably contain _both_ a rename of `foo.txt` to `bar.txt` _and_ a file modification of `bar.txt`. Since you just said it's better to have those in separate commits, didn't the merge commit just defeat any benefits from _previous_ commits? Would it somehow know to follow the parent commit where the filenames were the same?

Comment: "… it is an emergent property of the commit parent chain". Right, and since the merge commit has _two_ parents, that's why I'm asking to clarify how Git handles following the file changes for the parents of a merge, if the filename is different for one parent.

Comment: No, it wouldn't "know". Commits don't contain any rename information (as I just said, and as you already know). If there is a commit in the history (merge commit or not) that involves (from the human point of view) both a rename and an edit of the same file with respect to one of its parents, then whether a `log --follow` will report this as the same file is indeterminate, depending on how much resemblance Git sees between the created file in this commit and the deleted file in the parent.

Comment: "The merging business seems to me to come out of left field; I don't see what it has to do with anything." Now do you see what it has to do with anything? And the answer to the question "… does the branch merging negate any benefits of using this technique in a branch?" you're saying is … "yes, the merge commit will negate the benefits of separate rename and modification commits in the branch?" Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: When you do a `git log` with `--follow`, by the way, what parentage is used for the history of a merge commit is up to you. If your goal is to follow the second parent, where the renaming is clearer, you can specify that. See the discussion of history simplification in the doc.

Comment: No, you're not. If, with respect to the first parent, the merge commit involves what a human would call renaming and editing of a file, there are no "benefits" to "negate". But with respect to the second parent, if you maintained the commits and did not squash them, and if you did a rename commit and an edit commit, then there's your history. So nothing was "negated". It's just a matter of _you_ following the history in a useful way.

Comment: Yeah the merge part seems irrelevant. If e.g. the file `a` originated on branch `b` which got renamed using method 2 and then merged into branch `main` then you could follow the history just as well as if there was no merge.

Answer (score 5):

Git logging on the history of a file is an *emergent* property of the commit parent chain.

What I mean by that is that if you rename a file and then commit, then from Git's point of view, relative to that commit's parent, a file was deleted and a file was created. That's all. The notion that these are somehow the "same" file is in your head — but not in Git's. Git knows nothing of such a thing.

However, when following a file, Git *tries* to notice situations where a file might have been renamed. If the renaming of the file is *all* that happened to it between a commit and its parent, then Git can notice that the deleted file and the created file have identical content, and it can report this as a rename.

So, to sum up:

- If a file in commit A and a file in commit A-parent have the same name, they "are" the same file.
- If a file in commit A does not appear by that name in commit A-parent but a file with identical contents does, they "are" the same file with a rename.

So if you are careful to rename-and-commit and then edit-and-commit, you enable reliable following.

On the other hand, if a file in commit A does not appear by that name in commit A-parent but a file with *different* contents appears in A-parent and not in A, then whether following history will report these as the "same" file is something of a crap shoot. It depends on Git's algorithm, which has to do with resemblance between the files and so forth.

The involvement of a merge commit in the story changes nothing about what I just said. A merge commit is just a commit — it simply happens to have two parents. But in comparing the merge commit with *either* of its parents, Git will obey the logic I just enunciated. The existence of the other parent does not inform Git's logic with regard to this parent.

To illustrate, I'll start with this graph:

```
* ace8b40 (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'br'
|\
| * 487c79f (br) edited c
| * d9d1fec renamed a to c
* | c6abcc2 b
|/  
* 139a494 edited a
* 6b3d147 a
* 4eb0507 initial
```

Here, `main` is a merge commit and has two parents: c6abcc2 and 487c79f. Let's talk first about the first parent.

As far as Git is concerned, comparing `main` and its first parent, file *a* was deleted and file *c* was created. They have nothing in common. So if you follow the first parent in the chain, that's what Git reports:

```
% git log --first-parent --stat --oneline
ace8b40 (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'br'
 a | 1 -
 c | 1 +
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
c6abcc2 b
 b | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
139a494 edited a
 a | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
6b3d147 a
 a | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
4eb0507 initial
```

As you can see, Git says that file *a* was removed and file *c* was added. But if we follow *both* parents, we see a very different report along the branch `br`:

```
% git log --stat --oneline --graph 
*   ace8b40 (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'br'
|\  
| * 487c79f (br) edited c
| |  c | 2 +-
| |  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
| * d9d1fec renamed a to c
| |  a => c | 0
| |  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
* | c6abcc2 b
|/  
|    b | 1 +
|    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
* 139a494 edited a
|  a | 2 +-
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
* 6b3d147 a
|  a | 1 +
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
* 4eb0507 initial
```

The notation `a => c` tells you that between *this* commit and its parent, Git understands file *a* as having been renamed to *c*.

Thus, if we ask to follow the history of just file *c*, what we get will depend on how we traverse parents. If we follow it just along the first parent, the history stops dead immediately, because as far as the first parent chain is concerned, *c* was simply created out of nothing:

```
% git log --stat --oneline --graph --first-parent --follow -- c
* ace8b40 (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'br'
|  c | 1 +
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

But if we traverse both parents, it's a different story:

```
% git log --stat --oneline --graph --follow -- c 
... 
| * 487c79f (br) edited c
| |  c | 2 +-
| |  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
| * d9d1fec renamed a to c
| |  a => c | 0
| |  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
...
* 139a494 edited a
|  a | 2 +-
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
* 6b3d147 a
|  a | 1 +
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Here, the entire story of *a* right back to its creation counts as part of the history of *c* because the history being traversed includes `br` and so the rename is taken into account.

Comment: +1 on the detailed explanation. Do you have a scripted way to quickly set up that history ? it could be worth it to show what information is displayed when you use one of the [`--diff-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-mergesoffnoneonfirst-parent1separatemcombinedcdense-combinedccremerger) options of `git log`, like `git log -c` or `git log --cc`

Comment: for the OP's attention: this answer gives a very illustrated example of how "rename detection" with a merge commit can be skipped on one side of the history and active on the other ; it also shows what happens with a drastical amount of changes (in this example, "1 line change" means 100% modification on said file ...)

Comment: Let me see if I understand: if we rename and modify in separate commits, and each commit only has one parent, then most tools should follow the history with no problem. But if we have a commit with two parents, we would need a way to tell the tool to only follow the parent branch on which renames and modifications were made in separate commits. Assuming that this is always the branch merging _into_ `main`, an option `--second-parent` would do the trick. That option doesn't exist, so practically speaking for most tools the merge commit defeated the extra steps I did in the branch, right?

Comment: Or are you saying that most tools will try to follow _both_ parent branches, and simply come to a dead end on one, so that the history will look correct after all? So the extra work on the branch of using separate commits will turn out of be useful? But the output would look a little different than if it _only_ followed the "correct" parent branch, no? (Just making sure I'm understanding the implications as far as tools go.)

Comment: See, the problem is that I don't know what "most tools" even means. I don't know any GUI front ends that do not simply ask Git for this info; how else would you do it? So under the hood they are all doing some variant of what I've already described. But _what_ variant each one does, I'm like, meh. This is why I use the command line. I want control.

Comment: @GarretWilson What this answer (IMO) is saying is that the emergent property of file renames is dependent on the emergence ( ;) ) of the property—i.e. *how* you view the history. Interestingly, the Git maintainer [recently said that](https://lore.kernel.org/git/f5d21df1-2f52-8d19-4d2d-fa25ce9efbdc@game-point.net/T/#m572d4890dfade34a0b6011a8d227816ed24f494c) the rename-and-then-change strategy is “pure myth that would unlikely be helpful
in the bigger picture” (based on the `--first-parent` use-case).

Comment: "… I don't know what 'most tools' even means." From the question: "If nothing else it would be helpful to know if these techniques would help using the Git CLI, VS Code, and Eclipse." @matt you've helped me to know what happens with the Git CLI, thank you. It seems that if I go to a lot of trouble I can coax Git CLI to follow renames across merges. But I could already do that without putting renames in separate commits. The overall gist of the question is whether separate rename commits help me much for following history after the fact; so far it looks like I need to coax Git CLI either way.

Answer (score 3):

2nd approach should make `git log --follow -- bar.txt` work flawlessly.

If your only objective is to have a renaming detection for that specific file, I don't see a gain in your 3rd "modify on one side, renaming on the other" approach.
I only see more complications on on the renaming detection side of things, cutting off ways to follow a simpler path (like `git log --first-parent`), and the addition of a fork&merge sequence in your history which IMHO is not a bonus.

Refer to [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76086174/86072) who gives a very detailed and explanatory answer on how renaming detection gets handled around a merge commit

Comment: The question isn’t whether the 3rd approach is better, it’s “assuming I’m merging these changes from a branch, does 1 or 2 make any difference” - ie how does `git log --follow` cope with merge commits

Comment: I agree with @cmbuckley. The question about the merge commit is "does having it hurt?", instead of "does it help?" But this answer is nice and to the point, and [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76086174/184546) explains why the merge commit doesn't hurt.

Comment: reworded my answer. IMHO, ading a merge commit just for tha sake of representing a renaming does hurt -- at best, you get the same as the 2nd approach, and you may loose some obvious ways to detect things. The examples mentioned in the question and in matt's answer are suited for this short Q&A, they also however skip the parts where `git log` decides to "simplify the history" on its own and require adding `--full-history` (I must say I am not up to speed on the conditions that trigger this simplification, but I know I have already been bitten once or twice by it)